# Syntax error MySql trigger: While_Sym

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'am developing a small project with PHP and MySql on a Wamp server. I just discovered the wonderful principle of SQL triggers. Hum... well. It would be wonderful if I could use it.

Indeed I have a problem with the following script:

```
BEGIN
    SET @liste = NEW.reponse
    WHILE LEN(@liste) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF PATINDEX('%,%',@liste) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @choix = SUBSTRING(@liste, 0, PATINDEX('%,%', &liste))
            INSERT INTO resultat (referendum, choix) VALUES (NEW.id, @choix)
            SET @liste = SUBSTRING(@liste, LEN(@choix + ',') + 1, LEN(@liste))
        END
    END
END
```

I would like to execute this trigger after the insertion of a record in table `"Referendum"`. In this table, there is a field `"reponse"` which contains the different possible answers. This field contains this kind of data: `"Yes,No,I don't know"`. For each new question, I want to insert a new record in table `"Resultat"` per possible answer.

In my example, three new records: one for `Yes`, one for `No` and one for `I don't know`.

My code comes from an example on the internet but it doesn't work properly. SQL returns a syntax error with message `"While_Sym expected"...`

I tried to add semicolon following what I found on the internet but no way...

Comment: Can you please add entire error stack to your posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT 
ON Referendum FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE cnt int;
  DECLARE str varchar(100);
  Set cnt = CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.reponse) 
          - CHAR_LENGTH(Replace(NEW.reponse,',','')) +1;
  WHILE cnt > 0 DO
    Set str = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( New.reponse,',', -cnt)
      ,',',1);
    INSERT INTO resultat (referendum, choix) 
    VALUES (NEW.id, str);
    Set cnt = cnt - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7321/1

Some thoughts:

---

There are no `PATINDEX` nor `LEN` functions in MySql, they come from SQL Server.
Most functions are not standard in SQL, one shouldn't expect that something that works on database X should also work on database Y (and vice versa)
You always need to check the manual.

---

There is difference in MySql between `@variable` and `variable` - they are not the same (opposite to SQL Server where there is only one kind of variables --> `@variable`).
Please refer to documentation to learn about `@user_definied_variables` and `local_variables`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html

---

Depending on your client software you may need to use also `DELIMITER xx` command, for example in mysql console client or MySql-Workbench you need something like this to create a trigger without syntax errors:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT 
    ON Referend ......
 ......
 ......
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm currently at work so impossible to try. However, you gave me very usefull tips which allow me to extend my knowledge and search more about triggers. Actually, I didn't know that they were a difference between SQL Server and MySql. Thank you a lot.